# How to use proxies with authentication in my HTTP requests?

Tags: go, proxy, get, request

I have a proxy IP Address (that also require a username and password). When i try using them to visit webpages, i get "Proxy Authentication Required".

I'm found this other Stackoverflow post from 2016, and this Github Issue that was closed, but they don't provide anything useful:

- [Proxy golang https](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40676825/proxy-golang-https)
- https://github.com/golang/go/issues/22288

Any suggestions?

**EDIT:**
Saw this post: [Setting up proxy for HTTP client](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14661511/setting-up-proxy-for-http-client)

It's kinda close. However, for some urls I'm able to get a successful response using my proxy, but for certain urls, I get a "Proxy Authorization Required".

Answer (score 13, accepted):

If you're following this [authorized proxy tutorial](https://www.admfactory.com/how-to-setup-a-proxy-with-authentication-for-http-client-in-golang/), the additional step you would have to do is to set up the HEADER in the transport.

```
auth := "username:password"
basicAuth := "Basic " + base64.StdEncoding.EncodeToString([]byte(auth))
transport.ProxyConnectHeader = http.Header{}
transport.ProxyConnectHeader.Add("Proxy-Authorization", basicAuth)
```

Comment: If there are other headers required by the request, such as Content-Type or Accept, you should also add them to the ProxyConnectHeader.

Answer (score 0):

to add authorization, you may need to add a header:

```
auth := "{user}:{password}"
basicAuth := "Basic " + base64.StdEncoding.EncodeToString([]byte(auth))
request.Header.Add("Proxy-Authorization", basicAuth)
```