# How do I auth a user:pass proxy in golang

Tags: go, proxy, request, proxy-authentication

I am trying to use a user:pass proxy in my request in golang, and I am getting `proxy authentication required`` when I run it

here is my code:

```
var ip string = "123.45.67.890:54400:user:pass"

func main() {

    proxy := "http://" + ip
    proxyURL, err := url.Parse(proxy)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }

    urlStr := site
    url, err := url.Parse(urlStr)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }

    transport := &http.Transport{
        Proxy: http.ProxyURL(proxyURL),
    }

    jar, _ := cookiejar.New(nil)

    client := &http.Client{
        Jar:       jar,
        Transport: transport,
    }

    req, _ := http.NewRequest("GET", url.String(), nil)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }

    auth := "johndoe2x:johndoe2x"
    basicAuth := "Basic " + base64.StdEncoding.EncodeToString([]byte(auth))
    req.Header.Add("Proxy-Authorization", basicAuth)
    req.Header.Add("accept", "text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/avif,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8,application/signed-exchange;v=b3;q=0.9")
    req.Header.Add("accept-language", "en-US,en;q=0.9")
    req.Header.Add("upgrade-insecure-requests", "1")
    req.Header.Add("user-agent", userAgent)

    res, err := client.Do(req)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }

    log.Println("statusCode:", res.StatusCode)
    
    data, err := ioutil.ReadAll(res.Body)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
    log.Println(string(data))

}
```

Again, when I run this I get `Time_here Get "https://site_here/": Proxy Authentication Required`
I have been stuck on this for a few hours, and Im not sure exactly how to do it in Go, I was able to do it in JS with a var for user and pass but this one is giving me some trouble in Golang

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to use proxies with authentication in my HTTP requests?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53406874/how-to-use-proxies-with-authentication-in-my-http-requests)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are adding the proxy authentication headers to the request which will go to the target server. What you have to do is to add this header to `transport`.

Replace `req.Header.Add("Proxy-Authorization", basicAuth)` with

```go
transport.ProxyConnectHeader = http.Header{}
transport.ProxyConnectHeader.Add("Proxy-Authorization", basicAuth)
```

Comment: cool, so is auth :=  `` johndoe2x:johndoe2x" `` correct or should I use auth := `` "user:pass" ``

Comment: The basic auth syntax is `base64(username:password)`

Comment: yes but do I actually put the username and password in those fields or do I actually type ```username:password```

Comment: You replace those fields eith the username and password.